# Codeigniter Pagination: How to properly do results numbering

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

How can I properly do the the numbering of the results? What i did was

```
<?php  
                      if($results)
                        {      
                        $x = 1;                                     
                            foreach ($results as $data) 
                            {   
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>' . $x++. '</td>';
                                echo '<td><a href="'.base_url().'index.php/view/item/'.$data->item_id.'">' . $data->item_id . '</a></td>';
                                echo '<td><a href="'.base_url().'index.php/view/item/'.$data->item_id.'">' . $data->item_name . '</a></td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $data->item_category . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $data->item_costprice . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $data->item_retailprice . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>' . $data->item_tax . '%</td>';                                  
                                echo '</tr>';
                            } 
                          }  
                      ?>
```

But it has the same numbering per page.

[image]

Comment: Has my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

The numbering starts with 1 because thats the value you assign to it before the loop starts.

Assuming you pass the page number to your controller your could do the following:

`$x = count($results) * ($pagenumber-1);//use count or some other type of count method`

This will make the $x value 1 on the first page, 31 on the second page, 61 on the third page etc...

Then inside the loop change `$x++` to `++$x` otherwise the first page will be counted from 0 to 29.